# Sugar crm suctom field sql select error

Tags: sql, sugarcrm

I've added few additional fields to Accounts module. Also added same fields to detailed search. One field is decimal, another text, filled from drop down menu. After running a test search everything looked fine. But not long time ago I needed to see all the items in the search. Search was made using my new added fields as parameters. As you may already know, search in sugar crm shows only first 20 items. So, after trying to access another 20 items i've got an empty list. 
sugarcrm.log showed me sql query error:

```
11/12/12 00:09:33 [6300][ca4960aa-6cce-065a-be1d-4fa7b40db052][FATAL]  Query Failed:SELECT TOP 21 * FROM
(SELECT  ROW_NUMBER()
OVER (ORDER BY accounts.name) AS row_number,
accounts.id  ,
**accounts_cstm.print_srv_prov_c**, 
accounts.name , 
accounts.billing_address_city , 
accounts.billing_address_country , 
accounts.phone_office  , 
LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(jt0.first_name,'')+N' '+ISNULL(jt0.last_name,'')))     assigned_user_name , 
jt0.created_by assigned_user_name_owner  , 
N'Users' assigned_user_name_mod, 
accounts.annual_revenue , 
accounts.account_type , 
**accounts_cstm.print_srv_prov_c** , 
accounts.assigned_user_id  
FROM accounts   
LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c   
LEFT JOIN  users jt0 ON accounts.assigned_user_id=jt0.id AND jt0.deleted=0 AND jt0.deleted=0 
where ((accounts.account_type in (N'potencial_client') ) AND (     accounts_cstm.print_srv_prov_c in (N'itel'))) AND accounts.deleted=0 
) AS a
WHERE row_number > 20::: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]The     column 'print_srv_prov_c' was specified multiple times for 'a'.
```

All fields were added using Studio tool, and source code has been intact. 
sql error is happening, because column `accounts_cstm.print_srv_prov_c` is used two times. Why this is happening and how to fix it.

I am Using SugarCRM CE 6.4.4

Comment: link to sugarCRM forum [After searching by custom field sugar shows only first 20 items](http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f3/after-searching-custom-field-sugar-shows-only-first-20-items-83563/)